# Getting the first character of each word in a String array and its frequency

Tags: java, arrays, string, word-frequency

I have an array of Strings, for example:

```
String[] words = {"apple", "peach", "apricot"};
```

How do I print out the first letters of each string with their corresponding frequency?

For the example above, my expected output is:

```
a - 2
p - 1
```

I have no idea how to do this. Note that the contents of the string array is user defined and not predefined in the program.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] words = new String[20];
HashMap holder = new HashMap();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter word #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
    words[i] = input.next();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
        if (words[i].charAt(0) == words[j].charAt(0)) {
            freq += 1;
            holder.put(words[i].charAt(0), freq);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are loads of ways. use a loop with method like `charAt()` or `subString()` and then a Map

Comment: Its homework. isn't it?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder - Good homework questions are always welcome on SO. :)

Comment: Start with a loop, to loop through the array. Have a map to hold the the first letters and increment their counts as you find them in the array.

Comment: ohh I see, there is teaching service certainly available here... ;)

Comment: @TheLostMind true, but always nice when people show what they have done and not just asked people to completely do the HW for them. Good programmers learn to process the idea and ways of solving it, hence showing what you have done is nice before asking..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of any lack of evidence that the questioner tried to solve his problem himself.

Comment: I have edited my question for you people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it and this is what I did:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter word #" + (i+1) +": ");
        words[i] = input.next();
        if (map.containsKey(words[i].charAt(0)))
    {
        map.put(words[i].charAt(0), (int)map.get(words[i].charAt(0))+ 1);
    }
    else
    {
        map.put(words[i].charAt(0), 1);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not wanting to do your homework for you, but nevertheless here's how to do it in one line...

```
Arrays.stream(wordArray)
  .map(s -> s.charAt(0))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, counting()))
  .forEach((c, f) -> System.out.println(c + " - " + f));
```

In English, this code:

- streams the words
- changes them to the first letter
- collects them in a Map whose key is the letter itself
- changes the Map value list of letters to a count of the list size
- prints out the collected counts

Comment: You do it in one line but SO displays it on 4 lines.

Comment: So, if you don't want to do his homework; why are you doing it then? Tired on your reputation; looking for downvotes?

Comment: @Jägermeister there's no way a beginner could write this. If he submits this code, he will fail the subject or possibly be expelled for plagiarism. But analyzing and trying to understand this code can be instructive. Plus, learning the library APIs is learning the language.

Comment: @StephaneM I split the line over multiple lines deliberately for readability. You can remove the newlines to see what it looks like as one line.

Comment: The mapping can be done in the first argument to ```groupingBy```. And you could filter out empty strings first.

Comment: I don't get your point. You see, not even might a beginner not be able to solve the problem the way you did; he might even have a very hard time to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] test = { "apple", "clown", "banana", "ant", "batman" };
HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    if (map.containsKey(test[i].charAt(0))) {
        map.put(test[i].charAt(0), map.get(test[i].charAt(0)) + 1);
    } else {
        map.put(test[i].charAt(0), 1);
    }
}
for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("" + entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I tried using this but it only returns the NullPointerException

Comment: I have updated my answer. I changed the key into a Character.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void getStringInUpperCaseUsingStreams(Scanner sc2)
{ 
    String[] str= sc2.nextLine().split(" ");
    Arrays.stream(str).map(s-> s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+ s.substring(1))
        .forEach(s-> System.out.print(s+" "));
}
```